# Unable to hook ncurses functions with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, linux, hook, ncurses, ld-preload

I'm trying to hook some ncurses functions but they don't have any effect.
ncurses isn't statically linked, so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

test.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();

  getch();

  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -lncurses`

hook.cpp

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int getch() {
  typedef int getch ();
  getch* old_getch = (getch*) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getch");

  int result = old_getch();

  fprintf(stderr, "getch() = %i\n", result);

  return result;
}

int noecho() {
  typedef int noecho ();
  noecho* old_noecho = (noecho*) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "noecho");

  int result = old_noecho();

  fprintf(stderr, "noecho() = %i\n", result);

  return result;
}

int endwin() {
  typedef int endwin ();
  endwin* old_endwin = (endwin*) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "endwin");

  int result = old_endwin();

  printf("endwin called");

  return result;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc hook.cpp -o hook.so -shared -ldl -fPIC -std=c++11`

It sadly outputs nothing, and I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Probably need an `extern "c"` on your methods?

Comment: I've tried hooking other methods, such as rand(), and it worked perfectly. I've tried it, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Scrap that, `extern "c"` solved some of my problems, the noecho() and endwin() hooks work, but the getch() hook still won't budge

Comment: It might very well be a macro -- consult file _curses.h_

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a macro, it flew right over my head. Do you mind posting it as the answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification doesn't state `getch` has to be a function (not a macro). Actually, in ncurses-6.1, `getch` defined as

```
#define getch() wgetch(stdscr)
```

Nonetheless, there is a `getch` function in libncurses (which simply calls `wgetch(stdscr)`), so `dlsym(libncurses_handle,"getch")` does work.